# Change Hypersonic DS to MySql DS

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jboss, ejb, hsqldb

I try to switch an existing (**and well deploying**) application to MySql instead of Hypersonic. After I follow all steps from JBoss tutorial my application fails in deploy saying:

*org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table OLOLO refers to an unmapped class: com.trololo.pack.Class.*

MySql DB for JBoss has become filled with the data. But my app's DB is empty. I guess it is something wrong with hibernate, right?

I have JBoss 4.2.3. In the /default/deploy dir I have 2 *-ds.xml files. One for the JBoss and another for my app. Please share your ideas what is wrong there? Any help is welcome.

Comment: Can you please provide your hibernate.cfg.xml or persistence.xml file?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

Before I switched from Hypersonic to MySql I had well deploying and well running application. It's DB schema (myappdb in MySql) was generated by Hibernate and had no problem. After I switched to MySql I tried to make deploy both on the old schema in MySql (myappdb was filled with data) and with empty one. The result was the same.

Comment: I can't help you unless you provide those files. It looks like a mapping file problem. The only clue I can give you is to look for foreign keys that include OLOLO in your schema. There might be a table that need to be mapped to enforce a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. For the unknown reason Hibernate didn't allow to mention com.trololo.pack.Class in cfg.xml for OLOLO class. After I set annotations it worked.